# swapping nodes in binary tree

Tags: c#, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a function in **C#** that allows me to swap two nodes of a binary tree but it does not work as expected.

Here is the **class** with the **swap** method:

```
class Node
{
    public int value;
    public Node parent { get; set; }
    public Node left { get; set; }
    public Node right { get; set; }

    public Node addLeft(int value)
    {
        this.left = new Node(value);
        this.left.parent = this;
        this.left.left = null;
        this.left.right = null;
        return this.left;
    }

    public Node addRight(int value)
    {
        this.right = new Node(value);
        this.right.parent = this;
        this.right.left = null;
        this.right.right = null;
        return this.right;
    }

    public Node(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.parent = null;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public Node getRoot()
    {
        Node n = this;
        while(n.parent!=null)
        {
            n = n.parent;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static void swap(ref Node n1,ref Node n2)
    {
        //updating references of n1 and n2 parents
        if(n1.Equals(n1.parent.left)) //n1 is a left child
        {
            n1.parent.left = n2;
        }
        else if(n1.Equals(n1.parent.right)) //n1 is a right child
        {
            n1.parent.right = n2;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Something is wrong");
        }
        if (n2.Equals(n2.parent.left)) //n2 is a left child
        {
            n2.parent.left = n1;
        }
        else if (n2.Equals(n2.parent.right)) //n2 is a right child
        {
            n2.parent.right = n1;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Something is wrong");
        }
        //updating references of n1 and n2 childs
        if(n1.left != null)
        {
            n1.left.parent = n2;
        }
        if (n1.right != null)
        {
            n1.right.parent = n2;
        }
        if (n2.left != null)
        {
            n2.left.parent = n1;
        }
        if (n2.right != null)
        {
            n2.right.parent = n1;
        }
        //Swapping n1 and n2 references
        Node t_p = n1.parent;
        Node t_l = n1.left;
        Node t_r = n1.right;
        n1.parent = n2.parent;
        n1.left = n2.left;
        n1.right = n2.right;
        n2.parent = t_p;
        n2.left = t_l;
        n2.right = t_r;

    }
}
```

---

And here is my **main** function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node root = new Node(10);
        Node a = root.addLeft(1);
        Node b = root.addRight(2);
        Node c = a.addLeft(3);
        Node d = a.addRight(4);
        Node e = b.addLeft(5);
        Node f = b.addRight(6);
        Node g = d.addLeft(7);
        Node h = d.addRight(8);
        Node.swap(ref a,ref d);
        Console.WriteLine("Value is: " + root.left.value);
        Console.WriteLine("Value is: " + root.left.right.value);
        Console.WriteLine("Root: " + a.getRoot().value);
        Console.WriteLine("Root: " + d.getRoot().value);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

---

The output of the code above is:

```
Value is: 4
Value is: 1
```

It hangs after the second Console.WriteLine and I don't understand why. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

And if I try to swap the nodes multiple times, the **"Something is wrong"** exception is thrown.

Comment: Why are you passing your nodes with `ref` to `swap`?

Comment: It could have hung only because getRoot doesn't return, which means that you might've messed up changing parents.

Comment: It would also help if you defined in your question exactly what swap is supposed to achieve. I *think* you are trying to swap just the nodes themselves and not the whole subtrees.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to swap the nodes and not the subtrees

Comment: My advice, pull out *all* of the information you need before assigning anything, and then assign everything to what it should be.  You're running into the problem where you change certain values, and then assign the changed values to other values when you really wanted the old values.  If you order everything perfectly you can actually get away without storing as much, but then you run into bugs like this if you don't get it exactly right.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that one of the nodes is a child of the other. Somewhere in the code you swap something and then swap it back by mistake. Try swapping nodes which are not related.

Comment: @lared The code works fine when neither is the parent of the other.  That's (the cause of) his bug.

Comment: Is it an actual requirement that no new nodes are created to make the swap happen? Also, do the nodes have to swap? As far as I can see as aren't taking the child trees with, couldn't you just swap values instead of the entire node?

Comment: I've debugged it on paper, it seems like even the first swap of the parent children undoes itself.

Comment: @BradD He *is* moving all of the children, *not* just the values.

Comment: @Servy An earlier comment implies that they are only trying to swap the nodes not the subtrees.

Comment: It is not possible to swap the sub-trees if they overlap without some guidance on how to handle that.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement your own binary tree? Is this homework? There are many collections available in .NET and unless you have a specific need I don't think inventing your own is a good option. If it is homework though then you may find the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289150(v=vs.71).aspx of interest.

Comment: @Onots well, essentially to achieve the same result for this example, you could swap values and leave the actual nodes alone otherwise.  I'm guessing it is either homework or a contrived example with simplified Nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (n.parent != null)
```

This condition is never met so you're stuck in a while loop.

Your swap method creates a node with an infinite ancestor tree (parent).  If you walk up the current node `n` in `.getRoot()` you never find a null parent.

**Here is the state of the tree before we begin swapping**

```
             ((Root(10))
            /           \
          a(1)          b(2)
         /    \        /   \
      c(3)    d(4)   e(5)  f(6)
             /    \
           g(7)   h(8)
```

If you swap only the child nodes for a & d, you end up with an circular reference for parent.

Something more like this for your swap method should work.  I left this verbose for clarity's sake.

```
  public static void swap(ref Node A, ref Node B)
    {
        var newA = new Node(B.value);
        var newB = new Node(A.value);

        newA.left = A.left;
        newA.right = A.right;
        newA.parent = A.parent;

        newB.left = B.left;
        newB.right = B.right;
        newB.parent = B.parent;

        // Fix up parent node for A
        if (A.parent.left == A)
        {
            // A is a left node
            A.parent.left = newA;
        }
        if (A.parent.right == A)
        {
            // A is a Right node
            A.parent.right = newA;
        }

        // Fix up parent node for B
        if (B.parent.left == B)
        {
            // B is a left node
            B.parent.left = newB;
        }
        if (B.parent.right == B)
        {
            // B is a right node
            B.parent.right = newB;
        }


        if (newA.right == B)
        {
            // If B was a right child of A, update reference to newB
            newA.right = newB;
        }
        if (newA.left == A)
        {
            // If B was a left child of A, update reference to newB
            newA.left = newB;
        }

        if (newB.right == A)
        {
            // If A was a right child of B, update reference to newA
            newB.right = newA;
        }
        if (newB.left == A)
        {
            // If A was a left child of B, update reference to newA
            newA.left = newB;
        }

        // Update child references to be orphaned to point to new parents for A
        A.left.parent = newA;
        A.right.parent = newA;

        // Update child references to be orphaned to point to new parents for A
        B.left.parent = newB;
        B.right.parent = newB;

        // Final Swap to update ref types
        A = newA;
        B = newB;

    }
```

**Desired State after the swap**

```
         ((Root(10))
        /           \
      d(4)          b(2)
     /    \        /   \
  c(3)    a(1)   e(5)  f(6)
         /    \
       g(7)   h(8)
```

Here is some quick & dirty verification code that runs in the console.  I haven't checked all possible cases, but it seems to update all the relevant nodes in this case now.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new Node(10);
        var a = root.addLeft(1);
        var b = root.addRight(2);
        var c = a.addLeft(3);
        var d = a.addRight(4);
        var e = b.addLeft(5);
        var f = b.addRight(6);
        var g = d.addLeft(7);
        var h = d.addRight(8);
        Node.swap(ref a, ref d);

        if (root.left.value != 4) 
            throw new ApplicationException("New Root --> left --> value != 4 as expected");
        Console.WriteLine("New root --> left node has correct value of 4");

        if ((root.left.right.parent != root.left))
            throw new Exception("and root --> left --> right has incorrect parent");   
        Console.WriteLine("Root --> left --> right has the correct parent"); 

        if (root.left.right.value != 1)
            throw new ApplicationException("New Root --> left --> right --> value did not equal 1.");
        Console.WriteLine("New Root --> Left --> right has the correct value of 1");

        if (root.left.right.left.value != 7)
            throw new ApplicationException("New Root --> left --> right --> left --> value was not 7 as expected.");
        Console.WriteLine("New Root --> left --> right --> left.value had a value of 7 as expected");

        if (root.left.right.left.parent != root.left.right)
            throw new ApplicationException("New Root --> left --> right --> left --> parent was not root --> left --> right as expected");
        Console.WriteLine("New Root --> Left --> right --> left has the correct value of 7 and expected parent");


        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: This only leads to the question of why the parent isn't being set to the correct value, causing a loop.

Comment: The question was ' Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?'  This is why it is stuck in a loop.

Comment: And this doesn't answer that question.  Or at the very least, the answer is so completely vague as to be entirely unhelpful.  If you had said, "because you have a bug" then you'd be technically right, and equally unhelpful.

Comment: @ChrisBallance: And you've not really answered that question. You've just restated the symptoms.

Comment: Updated the answer as I had time to add more specifics.

Comment: Now it's just incorrect.  He's not just updating the children.  He's updating all of the right values, he's just doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Your most recent edit is *still* wrong.  It doesn't update the parent reference of all of the children, or the child references of the parents.

Comment: Updated source code to work for all the cases I missed in the previous version.

Comment: We somehow ended up with an orphaned child who became his own father, grandfather, and on down the line :-)

Comment: FYI: Fails if you swap with a leaf node. eg. `swap(d, e)`

Comment: Thanks @rageit, I'll fix that case when I have a second to have another look.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what your swap function should be doing, it should be as simple as this:

```
    public static void swap(Node n1, Node n2)
    {
        Node left1 = n1.left;
        Node left2 = n2.left;
        Node right1 = n1.right;
        Node right2 = n2.right;
        Node parent1 = n1.parent;
        Node parent2 = n2.parent;

        n1.left = left2;
        n2.left = left1;

        n1.right = right2;
        n2.right = right1;

        n1.parent = parent2;
        n2.parent = parent1;
    }
```

What I think you need to do is simple swap n1's left and right with n2's left and right. No need for `ref`'s either, since its a reference type and not a value type.

Comment: Parent nodes also need to be swapped.

Comment: It could also be done by simply swapping the values, but in this case one has to make sure that there are no references to the nodes of the tree elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning the unnecessary `ref`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this line:

```
if (n1.right != null)
{
    n1.right.parent = n2;
}
```

If n2 is the right child of the n1, as in this case, `n1.right`is`n2`, so `n1.right.parent = n2` is actually `n2.parent = n2` which causes the loop.

To solve the problem you have to either make copies of the nodes and then replace them, or try to do both swaps atomically and independently.